# Can't attach to Windows service that is sleeping

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug native service written in C++. 
In the method
`extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int /*nShowCmd*/)`  method, I have added `::Sleep(120000);` (i.e sleep for 2 minutes.) and placed breakpoint on the line that follows the sleep, so it would stop on a break point.

From VS, I attach to the process. VS kicks in, does something and then disconnects the debugger. 
I have also tried other suggestions: `DebugBreak();` and `_ams`, but they don't work either.

Comment: Sleep for 2 minutes? Why? Set up VS to the point you're ready to click the attach button, start the service, Alt+Tab to VS, and click the button. That shouldn't take more than a few seconds. VS is probably stopping debugging because the service isn't doing anything because you've sent it to a cave for a long winter's hibernation rather than a quick pause to attach a debugger.

Comment: When a debugger attaches to an active process, all threads in the process are suspended, then the debugger receives details about all of the threads and loaded modules in the process, and then the threads are resumed. The first thread to resume triggers a breakpoint exception to the debugger to signal the process is running again. But if all of the threads were already suspended/sleeping before the debugger attached, I don't know if that breakpoint is still triggered right away. Maybe it is not, and VS is timing out waiting for it?